# Facebook App "Misconfigured for Mobile Access" - Works in different places depending on Facebook settings, but not everywhere at once

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I've developed a Facebook Web App (so, one that lives inside an iFrame when you load it at apps.facebook.com/myappname).

In the Facebook App settings, I've set the "App on Facebook" section to include the canvas URL and secure Canvas URL.

If I also check the "Mobile Web" section and enter the secure canvas URL for the Mobile Site URL, then whenever I load the app from a mobile browser (e.g., iPhone, iPad), I get the following error: 
"The mobile version of the app "APPNAME" is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access."

I also see the same error if I try to go to the App from the Facebook iOS app.

However, if I do NOT a Mobile Site URL, then I don't see any errors in mobile safari, but I get a different error trying to link to the app from within the Facebook iOS app: 
"Either this application has not configured its Mobile Web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application. Unable to redirect."

I've done a lot of searching and I'm not able to find clear direction on what the correct combination of settings is. Should I be specifying a mobile URL? Can it be the same as the canvas URL? etc.

I currently Don't have anything specified in the "App Domains" field of the App Settings, because of a documented bug that seems to say having that can break things (and it does cause errors when that's in place).

As for the code on the app itself, it's not doing anything complex, the base of the code is just doing an authentication using the PHP SDK, like so:

```
<?php
    // get user from the facebook object
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $config['appId'],
        'secret' => $config['secret'],
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // if user is not loggedin, redirect to loginpage
    if(!$user){
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'redirect_uri' => 'MY_APP_URL_HERE'
        ));
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$login_url';</script>";
        exit();
    }

    //get user from the facebook object
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
?>
```

Any assistance or leads that anyone can offer here would be very, very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a workaround posted in the comments on the fb bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124226157757972

Kirill Kazakov · Software Developer at Ecwid
Interesting workaround is to remove referrer from the javascript-based redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the redirect_uri it **can't** point at the canvas app URL on mobile devices. Try adding a query string variable to your mobile URL and detect for that when determining your redirect_uri, or if you don't need to control the redirect_uri, just omit it (it's not required parameter). I'm not sure why FB doesn't just have it then redirect again to the mobile URL instead of giving an error - guessing because they would be breaking the behavior explicitly specified by the developer when setting the redirect_uri.